# UiLocalNotifications Based on Id's

Tags: iphone, xcode, uilocalnotification

Is there any tutorial on storing UIlocalNotifications based on there Id's and cancelling the notifications based on there Id's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in local notification u have userdictionary by this dictionary u cancele your notification.

- http://www.picksourcecode.com/ps/ct/161237.php
- http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/local-push-notification-sample-code-os.html
- http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/7/31/adding-local-notifications-with-ios-4.html

use this code

in the time set local notification u set the id in user info.

```
NSMutableArray *SheduleArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications]];
for(int s=0;s<[SheduleArray count];s++){
    UILocalNotification *Not=[SheduleArray objectAtIndex:s];
    int getId=[[Not.userInfo valueForKey:@"Id"] intValue];
    if(getId==yourId)
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:Not];
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks for these links but all these links will not explain how to cancel the notifications based on ID's

Comment: can you explain how r u adding notification and how r u cancelling the notification where i have to place the above code

Comment: when u set local notification in local notification u have userinfo dictionary. in this dictionary u set your id for a key. and when u want to cancel notification  wright abovw method.

Comment: ya but i don't want to run the timer when my application is closed i want to cancel the notification in a specific day and this cancelling i have to do when i set my notification.

Comment: i think u can't do this if u want to cancel notification when application close or go to back ground then call above function their. like application Terminate delegate or background delegate method.

Comment: ok i placed the above code in applicationDidEnterBackground: function . so basically in my app i have start date and enddate b/w those dates i need to show the notifications and after the enddate i need to cancel that notification please can you provide any tutorial for start date and end date

Comment: when your application is comming in foreground in this delegate method u check how many notification date is today date. for this u set end date in user info and compare when application will comming foreground.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3623/discussion-between-ron-and-ram)