# How to save date in nuserdefaults in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am saving my date selected from datepicker in nuserdefaults. When I select the date from date picker say 9.52 AM and click on the save button the date selected is getting saved in userdefaults and in SQLite. If I select another date to set another alarm say 9.54 AM and click on the save button, both the dates are getting saved in SQLite but the problem is the earlier 9.52 date is getting overrided by 9.54 in nsuserdefaults and so the notification for the last added date in userdefaults is shown.

I want that if I select 9.52AM and then click save and then select 9.54 AM and click save both the time should be saved in userdefaults and the notification for 9.52AM should be shown first.

Comment: you need so save an array of your time in NSUserDefault.

Comment: @userar i have tried saving array of time in userdefault but array is not getting saved properly in userdefaults

Comment: @userar could u please tell me how to save array of date in userdefaults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you add date objects to array and than add to NSUserDefaults

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"date"]==nil)
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"date"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"date"]);
}
else
{
    NSArray *array = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"date"];
    NSMutableArray *array_dates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i =0;i<[array count];i++)
    {
        [array_dates addObject:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    [array_dates addObject:YourpresentdateObject];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:array_dates forKey:@"date"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"date"]);
}
```

Comment: this is to save in the userdefaults but now i want to retreive objects from the array .How to do that                     NSDate *newtestdate = (NSDate*)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"date"];

Comment: if you save NSDate object it will return array with date objects no need to typecast

Comment: array is not getting saved properly in userdefaults

Comment: how to retreive date from the array and save in the firedate property of localnotifictaion.i.e if a particular  date in the array becomes equal to the current date and time notification should be should be shown

Comment: if you want local notification go to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444487/uilocalnotifications-based-on-ids/7444535#7444535

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use different keys when you save the date using `NSUserDefaults`. Something like-

```
//Use whatever format you are using to save the date
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:952 forKey:@"alarm1"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:954 forKey:@"alarm2"];
```

You are currently using the same key, which is why it overwrites the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to override dates than use different keys for both the alarm.