# how to compare the array values and check it with the current date and set it ti the notification firedate

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am using an user defaults which contains array of dates .in this array i am storing all the dates selected from the date picker.i now want to compare each of these dates with the current date .when the date matches with the current date the notification should be shown .i have done the code for traversing array but it is not working it does not match the date with the current date.And does not display the notification at the proper time.
    This is my code:

```
  -(void)scheduleNotification
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelAllLocalNotifications];


        timepicker = [[TTimePickerController alloc]init];
            //this is my new code.
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];


        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"time"];
        //array is my  array where i am saving all the the userdefaults objects 
        for (NSDate *date in array)
        {
            //here i am comparing my date object with current date object
            if ([date isEqualToDate:now]) 
            {
                itemDate = date;
                NSLog(@"%@",itemDate);
            } 



        }




        Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
        if (cls!= nil) {

            UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc]init];
        //in the notification firedate property i am setting the itemdate.

            notif.fireDate = itemDate;

            [app.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
            newstring = [app.dateFormatter stringFromDate:notif.fireDate];
            NSLog(@"new fire date:%@",newstring);

            notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            notif.alertBody = @"Alarm";
            notif.alertAction = @"View";
            notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber=1;
            notif.repeatInterval = 0;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
            [notif release];
        }
    }
```

//but the problem the date is not getting checked properly and notification is not displayed at proper time.

Comment: why are u do like this if u set local notification for a date it will come in that date no need to check every time today date is this and fire it.

Comment: in which format you are saving date in  NSUserDefaults

Comment: default format means can you provide me that format

Comment: i think firstly u lern about localnotification and then apply that because i am not under stand why u want like this

Comment: @Ron i dont understand what r u trying to say.Actually the date that i am selecting from the picker is getting save din the userdefaults for setting an alarm and from the userdefaults array it traverses every date object of the array whether it is equal to the current date.if it gets equal notification should get fired

Comment: @Ron this is for setting multiple alarms

Comment: same thing i told u if u want a particular date notification u directly set it why u want to compare date every time

Comment: can u explain wats ur requirment

Comment: @Narayana this is the format mm dd,YYYY  hh:mm:ss a

Comment: I thing if you save that date in NSUserDefaults as double value you can compare easily.

Comment: @Ron when i select a time say 4.00 PM from date picker and set an alarm and then set another alarm at 4.20 PM .first notification should be shown for 4.00 PM and then after that 4.20 .But now my problem is if i set an alarm at 4.00 PM and then 4.20 PM ,4.00PM alarm is overriden by 4.20 PM and the notification for 4.00PM is not shown.

Comment: @Narayana which date, the date selected from datepicker should i change it from date type to double.

Comment: @Ron how to solve this problem .if 2 or 3 alarms  are set, the last set alarm overides all the previous alarms and the notification of the previous alarms are not shown.

Comment: @Rani  double double_date = (double)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]; then you can save this double

Comment: @Rani double to date NSDate *date= [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:dateinDouble];

Comment: @Rani u use above function which u mention in ur question plz tell me

Comment: @Ron yes  this function is used to schedule notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove this line from your code and it will work fine.
If you call this function, all your old notifications are canceled.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Comment: i am having a problem in cancelling the particular notification

Comment: check this link                                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444487/uilocalnotifications-based-on-ids/7444535#7444535